# Intepreting the total number of magnons excited at temperature $T$

Tags: statistical-mechanics, quantum-spin, magnetic-moment, spin-statistics

Suppose a system is at thermal equilibrium.

The average value of the number of magnons excited in the mode $k$ is given by the Planck distribution:

$\langle{n_{k}}\rangle = \frac{1}{exp(\bar{h}\omega / k_{B}T) -1}$

The total number of magnons excited at temperature $T$ is

$\sum_{k}n_{k} = \int d\omega D(\omega) \langle n(\omega)\rangle$

where $\omega$ is the frequency

$D(\omega)$ is the density of states (the number of magnons modes per unit frequency range). So $D(\omega)d\omega$ gives me the number of magnon modes in the interval $d\omega$ and so $\int_{k} D(\omega)d\omega$ gives me the number of magnon modes over all frequency range.

I am unable to figure out what $D(\omega)\langle n(\omega)\rangle$ gives me. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: In your first equation nothing depends on $k$ in the r.h.s . What is the meaning of $k$ there? Should it be $\omega_k$?

Comment: It is implicit in Kittel's that $\omega = \omega_{k}$ @Javi
I had to figure this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That’s the average number of magnons for each frequency. $D(\omega)$ is the number of states for each frequency, and $n$ is the number of magnons per state for each frequency.

Comment: Your explanation is much clearer than Kittel. Thank you

Comment: @Physkid high praise!